# glueContext create_dynamic_frame_from_options exclude one file type from loading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

```
  raw_data_input_path = "s3a://{}/logs/application_id={}/component_id={}/".format(s3BucketName, application_id, component_id)

    df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type="s3",
                                                                connection_options={"paths": [raw_data_input_path],
                                                                                    "recurse": True},
                                                                format="json",
                                                                transformation_ctx=dbInstance)
```

my Bucket key contains 10 json files 1 txt file, i want to only include json files in the dynamic frame. Is that what the 'format' param is for in create_dynamic_frame_from_options

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create_dynamic_frame_from_options

"format – A format specification (optional). This is used for an Amazon S3 or an AWS Glue connection that supports multiple formats."

Answer (score 0):

`exclusions` parameter will help you to exclude files on `connection_options` object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-s3

```py
raw_data_input_path = "s3a://{}/logs/application_id={}/component_id={}/".format(s3BucketName, application_id, component_id)

df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [raw_data_input_path],
        "recurse": True,
        "exclusions": ["**.txt"],
    },
    format="json",
    transformation_ctx=dbInstance,
)
```